# Clarification about DecimalFormat API

Tags: java, api, decimalformat

Directly from this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

> In addition, DecimalFormat also recognizes as digits the ten
>   consecutive characters starting with the localized zero digit defined
>   in the DecimalFormatSymbols object.

"also recognize the ten consecutive characters starting with the localized zero digit" What would it be? I checked the [DecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) API and I have not found anything related to it.

Answer (score 0):

The zero-digit (the character used for zero) is locale-specific, but the 1..9 characters are everywhere following it. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html#getZeroDigit%28%29) says that (for example) for Arabic the zero-digit is different.

> Sets the character used for zero. Different for Arabic, etc.

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals